# Latching Relay Driving Idea

Tags: relay, h-bridge

I need to drive a 9V latching relay with single cell lipo 3.7V battery. So I designed a boost convertor. It brings 3.7V to 9V and than drive the latching relay with H-Bridge.

But with this design so many components needed for relatively easy job.

Question is what are the more clever ways to realize this circuit?

Comment: Use more batteries?  Use a dedicated chip?  How about showing us what you have, that way we can advise you how to optimize it.  At the moment all I can say is "Replace the block of components in the middle left with an LM317 ;)

Comment: You are right :) I have a lm2623 boost converter. I can't change the battery since I'm using solar charger and it can only charge single cell battery. And also in the place where I put these all not enough space for multicell lipos.

Comment: There are boost chips that take less components than that one.  Look for "switched capacitor" or "charge pump" boost converters.  A good tutorial: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/725

Comment: Is it a discrete component H-bridge, or are you using a proper H-bridge chip?

Comment: No, it is a proper one, bd6221f. It is not a common like L293D  chip I guess but has a low quiscent current (when using solar it is important).

Comment: Do you have a link to the relay's data sheet or a part number?

Comment: Actually it is a selonoid valve, but there is no techical data about it.

Comment: Only data is pulse width duration need to be 50ms. I bought long ago from aliexpress

Comment: OK. 9 volts, 50 milliseconds, how much current?

Comment: According to my crappy multimeter on average 100mA or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to get a relay that works at 3.7V.

Since you only need pulses of 9V to operate the latching relay, you might consider finding a 1:3 transformer, and driving the low-voltage side with your H-bridge directly from the 3.7V battery.

Or if you can find (or make) a transformer with a center tap, you can simplifiy the drive circuit.

Comment: Are you pointing AC transformer or DC one? Can you expand a little bit? With like DC-DC conversion technic or so?

Comment: Do I really need to explain that a transformer is two or more mutually-coupled coils? I guess using your terminology, that would be an "AC transformer".

Comment: Well, of course you don't. I guees you are pointing out to simply apply 3.7V to a 1:3 transformer for 50ms will result a 9V for 50ms at output. And center tap will be useful for positive negative voltages. Seems good idea. And no need of "angry" comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to drive a single-coil latching 9V relay from a 3.7V battery, your suggested circuit blocks are probably essential.

A 3VDC dual-coil relay would make things dead easy (a dual transistor and a dual diode, two parts!). Eg. [FDG6303](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDG6303N.pdf) + [BAV70](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BAV70LT1-D.PDF) for a telecom-style latching relay.

A 5VDC relay with a one-shot capacitive charge pump could eliminate the inductor, but the caps will probably be fairly large physically to generate the milliseconds-long-pulse.

You might be able to use CMOS buffers or gate drivers to drive the relay rather than building an H-bridge with many parts, depending on the relay. Then you have a "canned" boost converter configuration with a few parts to generate the 9V regulated and a driver chip.